# Prove an equation (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers

How can i prove this equation?

$$ {(1 + i\tan(x))^n \over (1-i\tan(x))^n} = {1 + i\tan(nx) \over 1-i\tan(nx)} , n \in  N$$

I tried to use a binomial theorem to open brackets, but it did not help.

Comment: $$\frac{1 + i\tan x}{1 - i\tan x} = \frac{\cos x+ i\sin x}{\cos x- i\sin x}.$$

Comment: $\tan \varphi = \frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi}$, and de Moivre's formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

${(1 + i\tan x)^n \over (1-i\tan x)^n} = {(\cos x + i\sin x)^n \over (\cos x-i\sin x)^n}= ( \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{-i \theta}} )^n = \frac{e^{i n\theta}}{e^{-i n\theta}} = {\cos (nx) + i\sin(nx) \over \cos(nx)-i\sin(xx)} =  {1 + i\tan(nx) \over 1-i\tan(nx)} , n \in  N$

Answer (score 1):

Key ideas.
Definition of tan.
Euler formula.